# Error while declaring a lambda function: declare an instance first

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand *lambda functions* (i.e. *anonymous functions*) in Haskell by writing a few simple functions that use them.

In the following example, I am simply trying to take in 3 parameters and add two of the three using an anonymous function and adding the third parameter after that. 
I am getting an error saying that I must declare an instance first.

```
specialAdd x y z = (\x y -> x + y) + z
```

I appreciate any explanation of why my example is not working and/or any explanation that would help me better understand lambda functions.

Comment: (\x y -> x + y) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
You try to add z to function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> `specialAdd x y z = (\x y -> x + y) + z`

In this example, what you are trying to do is add a function to a number, which is not going to work.  Look at `(\x y -> x + y) + z`: it has the form `a + b`.  In order for such an expression to work, the `a` part and the `b` part must be numbers of the same type.

Haskell is a bit of an unusual language, so its error messages are rarely of the form "you can't do that".  So what's going on here is that Haskell sees that `(\x y -> x + y)` is a function, and since in an expression like `a + b`, `b` must be the same type as `a`, it concludes that `b` must also be a function.  Haskell also allows you to define your own rules for adding non-built-in types; so it can't just give you an error saying "you can't add two functions," but instead the error is "you have not defined a rule that allows me to add two functions."

The following would do what you want:

```
specialAdd x y z = ((\x y -> x + y) x y) + z
```

Here you are applying the function `(\x y -> x + y)` to arguments `x` and `y`, then adding the result to `z`.

Answer (score 10):

A good way to practice anonymous function is to use them with high order function as fold or map.

Using map as an entry point,

Basic definition of map,

```
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : f xs
```

Built up an example,

```
>>> let list = [0..4]
>>> let f x = x + 1
```

Applying map we obtain,

```
>>> map f list 
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Now, we can omit the declaration of f and replace it using anonymous function,

```
>>> map (\x->x+1) list 
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

then we deduce,  **map f list == map (\x->x+1) list**, thus

```
f = \x-> x + 1 --- The same as f x = x + 1, but this is the equivalent lambda notation.
```

then starting with a simple function we see how to translate it into an anonymous function and then how an anonymous function can be rely to a lambda abstraction.

As an exercise try to translate f x = 2*x.

Now more complex, an anonymous function which take two arguments,

Again an working example,

```
>>> let add x y = x + y
>>> foldl' add 0 [0..4]
10
```

Can be rewrite using anonymous function as,

```
>>> foldl' (\x y -> x + y) 0 [0..4]
```

Again using equality we deduce that add = \x y -> x + y
Moreover as in hakell all function are function of one argument, and we can partial apply it, we can rewrite our previous anonymous function as, add = \x -> (\y -> x + y).

Then where is the trick ?? Because, I just show the use of anonymous function into high order one, and starting from that, showing how this can be exploited to rewrite function using lambda notation. I mean how can it help you to learn how to write down anonymous function ?

Simply cause I've give you (show you) an existing framework using high order function.
This framework is a huge opportunity to accommodate you with this notation.
Starting from that an infinity range of exercise can be deduce, for example try to do the following.

```
A - Find the corresponding anonymous function ?

1 - let f (x,y) = x + y in map f [(0,1),(2,3),(-1,1)]  
2 - let f x y = x * y in foldl' f 1 [1..5] 

B - Rewrite all of them using lambda notation into a declarative form (f = \x-> (\y-> ...)
```

And so on ....

---

To summarize,

A function as

```
(F0)   f x1 x2 ... xn = {BODY of f}
```

can always be rewrite as,

```
(F1)   f = \x1 x2 ... xn -> {BODY of f}
```

where

```
(F2)   (\x1 x2 ... xn -> {BODY of f})
```

F2 form are just anonymous function, a pure translation of the function into lambda calculus form. F1 is a declarative lambda notation (because we declare f, as we define it, binding it to the anonymous F2). F0 being the usual notation of Haskeller.

A last note focusing on the fact we can put parenthesis between the argument, this create a closure. Doing that mean that a subset of the function's code can be fully evaluated using a subset of the function's argument,  (mean converting to a form where no more free variable occurs), but that's another story.

Answer (score 3):

Here is correct form:
`specialAdd a b c = ((\x y -> x + y) a b) + c`

Example from Learn You a Haskell...:
`zipWith (\a b -> (a * 30 + 3) / b) [5,4,3,2,1] [1,2,3,4,5]`

Great explanation:
http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#lambdas

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand Labmbda/Anonymous functions help you declare a function "inline" without the need to give it a name. The "\" (ASCII for the Greek, λ) precedes the variable names for the expression that follows the "->". For example,

```
(\x y -> x + y)
```

is an anonymous (lambda) function similar to (+). It takes two parameters of type Num and returns their sum:

```
Prelude> :type (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a

Prelude> :type (\x y -> x + y)
(\x y -> x + y) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Your example is not working because, as others have pointed out, the right hand side of it is using a lambda function, (\x y -> x + y), as a parameter for  the (+) operator, which is defined by default only for parameters of type Num. Some of the beauty of the lambda function can be in its "anonymous" use. Vladimir showed how you can use the lambda function in your declaration by passing it the variables from the left side. A more "anonymous" use could be simply calling it, with variables, without giving the function a name (hence anonymous). For example,

```
Prelude> (\x y z -> x + y + z) 1 2 3
6

and if you like writing parentheses:

Prelude> (((+).) . (+)) 1 2 3
6
```

Or in a longer expression (as in your example declaration), e.g.,

```
Prelude> filter (\x -> length x < 3) [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
[[1],[1,2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `(+)` as something like `(Num a) => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> ??` which is not correct.

`(+)` is defined in the class `Num` and (a -> a -> a) is not an instance of this class.

What exactly are you trying to achieve ?